# What is the best way to conditionally set the choices of a `serializers.ChoiceField` based on the value given to another field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's assume I have a choice field named chart.
If the user inputs 'line' for the chart field, the following operations should be accepted: min, max, avg, and sum.
If the user inputs 'pie' for the chart field, the following operations should be accepted: count and top-count.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers


CHARTS = ['line', 'pie']
CHART_OPERATIONS = {
    'line': ['min', 'max', 'avg', 'sum'],
    'pie': ['count', 'top_count'],
}


class ChartDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    chart = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=CHARTS)
    # operation = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=CHART_OPERATIONS[chart])
```

Comment: What about having all choices available and adding conditional validators at serializer or model level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found is adding the conditional serializer fields inside the `__init__` method.

```py
import functools

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.serializers import fields


CHARTS = ['line', 'pie']
CHART_OPERATIONS = {
    'line': ['min', 'max', 'avg', 'sum'],
    'pie': ['count', 'top_count'],
}
ALL_OPERATIONS = list(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, CHART_OPERATIONS.values()))

class ChartDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    chart = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=CHARTS)
    # Be careful! Leave the following line as a comment
    # in case the user should not be able to see every operation
    # operation = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=ALL_OPERATIONS)

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=fields.empty, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(instance=instance, data=data, **kwargs)
        if data is not fields.empty:
            try:
                chart = data['chart']
                self.fields['operation'] = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=CHART_OPERATIONS[chart])
            except KeyError:
                # Do nothing. The invocation of 'is_valid' will raise
                # an exception anyway if the chart does not exist
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when you're saving your data with the serializer. After the validation like this:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
     serializer.object.operation = CHART_OPERATIONS[chart]
     serializer.save()
```

or you change the data that will be passed to the serializer like that. There are other ways to accomplish but you need to override serializer functions, hence this is the simplest and minimum coding required version.